# When i launch a pyqt6 qmessagebox from a function called by a watchdog event my program crashes

Tags: python, crash, watchdog, qmessagebox

qmessagebox pops up incomplete, title with text "(Not respondig)" besides and no main text into box
python pyqt6 and watchdog upgraded 04/08/2023

my code:

```
`import sys
import os
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMessageBox
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

# Clase para manejar los eventos de cambio de archivo o directorio
class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, observer):
        self.observer = observer
        super().__init__()

    def on_created(self, event):
        # Detener el observador
        self.observer.stop()
        self.observer.unschedule_all()
        # Mostrar mensaje de archivo creado
        QMessageBox.information(None, "Archivo creado", f"Se creó el archivo: {event.src_path}")

    def on_modified(self, event):
        # Detener el observador
        self.observer.stop()
        self.observer.unschedule_all()
        # Mostrar mensaje de archivo modificado
        QMessageBox.information(None, "Archivo modificado", f"Se modificó el archivo: {event.src_path}")

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Watchdog App'
        self.left = 100
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        # Botón para iniciar el watchdog
        self.btn_start = QPushButton('Iniciar', self)
        self.btn_start.move(50, 50)
        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.start_watchdog)

        # Botón para detener el watchdog
        self.btn_stop = QPushButton('Detener', self)
        self.btn_stop.move(150, 50)
        self.btn_stop.clicked.connect(self.stop_watchdog)

        self.show()

    def start_watchdog(self):
        # Directorio para monitorear
        path = os.path.join(os.getenv("USERPROFILE"), "Downloads")
        # Crear una instancia del observador y el manejador de eventos
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.event_handler = Handler(self.observer)
        # Asignar el observador al manejador de eventos y empezar a monitorear
        self.observer.schedule(self.event_handler, path, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        print(f"Watchdog activo: {self.observer.is_alive()}")

    def stop_watchdog(self):
        # Detener el observador
        self.observer.stop()
        self.observer.unschedule_all()
        self.observer.join()
        print(f"Watchdog activo: {self.observer.is_alive()}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec())`
```

i ve tried to launch same function from a button to evaluate behavior.
result: the problem does not repeat.
note: watchdog was still runing but no events raised
conclusion: the problem appears only when function is called by a watchdog event

Comment: I forgot to clarify that the instructions to stop watchdog before sending the message are not working, which means that I have not been able to stop watchdog

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can edit your questions and answers to clarify and add information.